# Error al saber si una tabla de MySQL esta vacia

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código php y no me detecta si hay algún registro en la tabla o no y no se que puede ser:

```
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$bd = "crypto4all";

//Creamos la conexión
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $bd) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la conexion de la base de datos");

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM criptomoneda");

if($consulta == '0'){
    foreach ($criptomoneda as $c) {
        mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO criptomoneda (nombre,ranking,volumen_24h,porcentaje_1h,porcentaje_24h,porcentaje_7d,fecha) 
        VALUES ('".$c['name']."','".$c['rank']."','".$c['24h_volume_usd']."','".$c['percent_change_1h']."','".$c['percent_change_24h']."','".$c['percent_change_7d']."','".$fecha."')");
    }
}else{
    foreach ($criptomoneda as $c) {
        mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE criptomoneda SET volumen = ('".$c['24h_volume_usd']."') WHERE nombre = '".$c['name']."'");
        mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE criptomoneda SET fecha = ('".$fecha."') WHERE nombre = '".$c['name']."'");
    }
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_query` retorna un objero no la cantidad de la columna count(), debes utilizar `mysqli_fetch_assoc` para obtener la fila de resultado y comparar por la columna

Comment: Tampoco funciona asi:
`$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM criptomoneda");

    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);

    if($row == 0)`

Comment: te añado una respuesta para que lo entiendas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_query` retorna un objero no la cantidad de la columna count(), debes utilizar `mysqli_fetch_assoc` por ejemplo para obtener la fila de resultados y comparar por la columna.

Ejemplo:

```
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$bd = "crypto4all";

//Creamos la conexión
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $bd) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la conexion de la base de datos");

// añadimos un alias para identificar mas facil:  AS total
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM criptomoneda");

// obtenemos la primera fila como array asociativo, en este caso solo tendremos una
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

// comparamos con el alias total que dimos en la consulta
if($row['total'] == '0'){
  // si no hay registros
}else{
  // si hay registros
}
```

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result` Me muestra el siguiente error con tu código. @Xerif

Comment: Cierto, tampoco me habia dado cuenta y muchas gracias, funciona genial. @Xerif